# Android room - Search by list of keywords (Contains)

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using Room database and my entity class has List of string attribute, lets call it `List<String> keys1`. I was able to save in database using `@TypeConverter`. Now I want to pass a list of strings which consists of keys, let's call it `List<String> keys2` and I want to check if any of my value in **keys1** matches any value in **keys2**. How can I solve this issue?

I already know that to match a signle values against of list of keys, I can do something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE key IN (:search)")
List<Article> find(List<String> search);
```

But what if instead of **key** I want to check against `List<String> keys`. Did a lot of research but couldn't find any decent solution.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check this one in KOTLIN

```
   @Query("select *from TABLE where id in(:ids)")
   fun getAll(ids: Array<String?>) : List<Data>
```

now call

```
    val ids = arrayOf("ids","ids")
    val a = db!!.doa().getAll(f)
    a.forEach {
        Log.d("Id",it.id!!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the keys list, then you can solve this issue by using `like` query. The following code snippet shows how to implement `TypeConverter` class. It sorts the list first and then converts it to a String.

```
public class ArticleKeyListConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromList(List<String> value) {
        java.util.Collections.sort(value);
        return String.join(",", value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<String> toList(String str) {
        return Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
    }
}
```

The `Dao` class should be like below:

```
@Dao
public interface ArticleDao {
    @TypeConverters(ArticleKeyListConverters.class)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE keys like '%' || REPLACE(:search, ',', '%') || '%'")
    List<Article> find(List<String> search);
}
```

**But it doesn't work.**

As I figured out, `Dao` class doesn't use `TypeConverter` for method input arguments that are List or Array of Room supported data types. So I wrote a new class to wrap List and used it as method input argument.

```
public class QueryCollection<T> {

    private List<T> list;

    public QueryCollection(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then I added a new method to `ArticleKeyListConverters` that converts `QueryCollection` to `String`.

```
public class ArticleKeyListConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromList(List<String> value) {
        java.util.Collections.sort(value);
        return String.join(",", value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<String> toList(String str) {
        return Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromCollecion(QueryCollection<String> collection) {
        return fromList(collection.getList());
    }
}
```

And finally modified `Dao` as bellow:

```
@Dao
public interface ArticleDao {
    @TypeConverters(ArticleKeyListConverters.class)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE keys like '%' || REPLACE(:search, ',', '%') || '%'")
    List<Article> find(QueryCollection<String> search);
}
```

**Important:** If your keys contain comma character, then this solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man! I'll try it and get back to you (y)

Comment: Did this answer help?

Comment: Hi! Sorry about the late reply. I thing there is an error in your Dao query. When I wrote the query it's giving "<expression> expected, got 'REPLACE'" error.

Comment: The app crashed when I run it. It says "wrong number of arguments to function REPLACE() ". I thing I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry man, little busy with work. Will update the question once I get free. Cheers :)